# cin not working, I get a runtime error or something

Tags: c++, runtime-error, cin

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int num;
    cout<<"Enter a number : ";
    cin>>num;
    cout<<"The number is : "<<num;
    return 0;
}
```

The above code produces output :

```
Enter a number :
```

and then a window saying

```
a.exe has stopped working
```

appears. This happens only with my laptop which runs windows 10.
The code runs without errors on my friend's computer which has the same compiler that I have.

What could the problem be ?

Comment: Try disabling your antivirus.

Comment: If you are using gcc /mingw make sure you don't have a dll conflict.

Comment: How do I know if I have a dll conflict ?